# What exaclty do we mean when we pass set the tuple "spark.some.config.option", "config-value" while creating Spark session?

Tags: scala, apache-spark

While creating spark session with builder pattern we often set config with `("spark.some.config.option", "config-value")`. What exactly do we mean by it and what is its significance ?

for example:

```
val spark=SparkSession.builder().appName("SPARK SQL EXAMPLE")
     .config("spark.some.config.option", "some-value").getOrCreate
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is one of the ways to control Spark's configuration used when creating or using the `SparkSession`. Spark has a long list of available configurations, each controlling a specific behavior that can be modified using different config values.

Here's a glossary of all the available configurations and their meaning: https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/configuration.html#available-properties

For example, using `.config("spark.shuffle.compress", "false")` would tell Spark not to compress shuffle files (not necessarily a good idea, just an example).

Comment: So I was trying to understand some code from a book and there it was written val 
  
 spark=SparkSession.builder().appName("SPARK SQL EXAMPLE")
     .config("spark.some.config.option", "some-value").getOrCreate




So when the code is executed what will be the tuple value exactly. I mean to say what driver program will substitute while running this code.

Comment: I guess "spark.some.config.option", "some-value" are just examples meant to say "place parameter name / value here", not real values

Answer (score 0):

Like every other framework out there, `Spark` provides a plethora of customizable knobs and levers in the form of [`Configurations`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/configuration.html). They can be set via a variety of ways including

- `spark-defaults.conf` file
- `spark-submit` options
- `SparkConf` object

---

While creating `SparkSession`, `Spark` API allows you to pass runtime config, which can be achieved via

- `SparkConf` object
- using `.config("key", value)` calls